# Generalizing an eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to shed some light on the following problem:

$$A_2 x = \lambda \odot A_1x$$

where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are known square matrices and $\odot$ is the element-wise operator. This generalize the notion of eigenvalue decomposition, where now the scaling $\lambda$ is a vector instead of a scalar value. Is there any sort of literature on this problem and relative solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ supposed to be fixed, or do you permit different $\lambda$s for different $x$s?

Comment: Different $x$s can have different $\lambda$s. I was thinking if this problem, although non convex, might have a global minimum in a way similar to an EVD

Comment: If $A$ and $x$ are given, then you can always find $\lambda_i$ that solve it, so long as $x_i$ isn't zero while $(Ax)_i$ is non-zero. Speaking loosely, there are way too many solutions.

Comment: In my case both $x$ and $\lambda$ are unknown

Comment: Yes, and there are tons and tons of solutions. Take any $x$ all of whose coordinates are non-zero, and you can find $ \lambda$ so that $(x, \lambda)$ form a solution.

Comment: It's kind of like asking for solutions of $y=x^2$ - half of all possible $y$ values lead to solutions.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

$(\lambda)_i = (A_2 x)_i / (A_1 x)_i$ is always a solution. The only possible complication is if the $i$th component of $A_1 x$ is zero.

Comment: Is it the only one solution?

Comment: When components of $A_1 x$ or $A_2 x$ become zero there are some complicated "if this, else if that" statements to make, but so long as there are no zeros, we're just asking "Solve $a_1 = m a_2$" $n$ times, once for each component.

Comment: However, neither $x$ nor $\lambda$ are known..

Comment: There are equations, like, say $x+y = 2, x-y = 0$, where the answer is "The only solution is $x=1, y=1$". Then there are equations like $y = x^2$, where the answer is "There are tons of solutions. You give me any positive $y$ and I'll give you two solutions, $(\sqrt y, y)$, and $(-\sqrt y, y)$". Regular eigenvalues questions generally have solutions like the first type, i.e. a few discrete values. Your question has whole infinities of different solutions, like the second type.

Comment: Also, to explicitly answer "is it the only one solution?" - No, almost every arbitrary choice of $x$ leads to a different $(x,\lambda)$ solution. The word "almost" is in there to deal with components equaling zero, as described above, which should happen for only a small set of $x$s.

Comment: Well, in principle also an eigenvalue problem has tons of solutions (not discrete), right? If you see it as an optimization problem minimizing multiple Rayleigh quotients, you get infinite solutions (perhaps without the orthogonality constraint).

Comment: Everything I've told you is true. Do with it what you want.